# Appstore EULA rejection for Payments - Subscriptions

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I tried to submit the in-app purchase and subscription items and received this rejection:

> Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions
>
> We noticed that your app did not meet all the terms and conditions for
> auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section
> 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.
>
> ￼We were unable to find the following required information in your
> app's binary:
>
> We were unable to find the following required item(s) in your app's
> metadata:
>
> – A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please add this missing information. If the
> above information is present, please reply to this message in App
> Store Connect to provide details on where to locate it.
>
> If you are using the standard Apple Terms of Use (EULA), you will need
> to include a link to the Terms of Use in your App Description. If you
> are using a custom EULA, add it in App Store Connect.

What should I do?

Currently I'm using apple standard EULA:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've figured this out by now, but I'm having the same problem.

Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement says:

```
You clearly and conspicuously disclose to users the following information regarding Your auto-renewing subscription:

 - Title of auto-renewing subscription, which may be the same as the in-app product name
 - Length of subscription
 - Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate
```

And in a different bullet point immediately below but with a lesser indentation it says:

```
- Links to Your Privacy Policy and Terms of Use must be accessible within Your Licensed Application.
```

I was missing the last bullet point in my app so, maybe that's the problem?

EDIT: Looks like that was the problem.  My submission was accepted after I added a link to my Privacy Policy and Terms of Use.